# Bootstrap 4 - Progress Bar Progression

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

Seems like Bootstrap 4 has changed the way you update the progression of your progress bar.

**Goal: Update the progress bar percentage on click**

```
<div  class="progress">
<div id='progressBar' class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

How I'm trying to Update the percentage:

```
$( ".nextStep" ).click(function() {
$( "#progressBar" ).css({"width": "90%"});
});
```

Comment: Whats about the aria-valuenow attribute? If you update this value aswell it will work maybe? Removing the aria-*-attributes should work aswell iirc

Comment: I could not get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This codesnippet works for me:

```
$(".nextStep").click(function() {
    $("#progressBar")
        .css({"width": "90%"})
       .setAttribute("aria-valuenow", 90);
});
```

Here is your example in a codepen: https://codepen.io/AndTheGodsMadeLove/pen/vYBGzeQ